# Android: Picasso doesn't work

Tags: android, image, picasso

**Case** :
I work on app which retrieve info about local venues based on coordinates from Foursquare API. All information is stored in the DB, including venue featured photo stored as prefix and suffix of the link. For the list representation I use recyclerview. I logged url links and they seem work fine. Here is my onBindViewHolder method:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
        Venue venue = venueList.get(position);
        String url = venue.getFeaturedPhotos().getItems().get(0).getPrefix() + "120x120" + venue.getFeaturedPhotos().getItems().get(0).getSuffix();
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).venueName.setText(venue.getName());
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).streetAdr.setText(venue.getLocation().getAddress());
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).rating.setText(venue.getRating().toString());
        Context context = ((ItemViewHolder) holder).venuePhoto.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(((ItemViewHolder) holder).venuePhoto);;
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).venue = venue;
    } else {
        ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

    }
}
```

This is how my item looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/venuePhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgDescr"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/ratingSample"
        android:textSize="45sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/venueName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rating"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/venuePhoto"
        android:text="@string/VenueNameSample"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/streetAdr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/venueName"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rating"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/venuePhoto"

        android:text="@string/addressSample"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be         `Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(venuePhoto);`. Currently, you load without a target.

Comment: Correct, at the moment it appears to just be loading the URL and doing nothing with it.

Comment: I'm dumb, sorry. I edited code but it didn't give any result

Comment: just loading wont work  you will have to specify a view it has to be loaded into as mentioned by @jorn

Comment: @AvinashJoshi I edited my question and code

Comment: try binding a static url to picasso check if it works. if it, you will know there is a problem with the urls you are binding if not then explore other things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by just adding uri parsing

```
String url = venue.getFeaturedPhotos().getItems().get(0).getPrefix() + "120x120" + venue.getFeaturedPhotos().getItems().get(0).getSuffix();
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
```